# How to make marker plot of ♡ on MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot

I know in MATLAB, the marker plot only like this table.
[image]

How to make the other marker plot symbol? Like "love" marker? '♡'? This is my code

```
clear all;
clc;
x=[1,2,3];
y=[3,2,1];
plot(x,y,'b♡','markerfacecolor','y','markersize',15);
grid on;
```

The 'b♡' give an error in the MATLAB because the '♡' symbol does not exist

Comment: You cannot use any custom marker symbol using `plot` or `scatter`, however, you can draw [text](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/93787-how-do-i-use-custom-markers-for-a-line-object-in-a-matlab-plot) (i.e. any font and symbol) anywhere you want

Comment: @rinkert Can you give me an example for drawing text in matlab?

Comment: It doesn't seem right that the "Is it possible..." question is a duplicate of "Custom Markers for...". The latter is a question specifically about raster images as markers. The former gives glyphs that can be displayed without the use of images as its example. This question is definitely a duplicate of the former though.

Comment: This slide is incomplete, one can also specify markers as vertical and horizontal lines, using `'vbar'` and `'hbar'`, respectively.

Comment: I have seen it before. But this is make the marker plot from images. Now I ask how to make marker plot from the 'character', not from images.

Comment: '''
clear all;
clc;
m = '\heartsuit';
x = 0:0.5:2*pi;    
y = sin(x);    
text(x,y,m,'fontname','Arial','color','red','FontSize',18);
grid on;
xlim([min(x) max(x)])    
ylim([min(y) max(y)])
'''